# Filtering object by value of other key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an object like this :

```
let data = {
    approval: [{
            name: 'XXXX',
            kode: '10'
        },
        {
            name: 'YYYY',
            kode: '12'
        },
        {
            name: 'ZZZZ',
            kode: '14'
        },
        {
            name: 'HHHH',
            kode: '09'
        }

    ],
    batas: "10"
}
```

I want to display the data that is equal to this condition (kode >= 10) so if the 'kode' is less than 'batas' it shouldn't appear, any help?

So in that case the output should be like this

```
approval: [{
        name: 'XXXX',
        kode: '10'
    },
    {
        name: 'YYYY',
        kode: '12'
    },
    {
        name: 'ZZZZ',
        kode: '14'
    }

]
```

the data comes from ajax,
Thanks for your help.

Comment: simple array filter should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the many ways to do what you want:

```js
    let data = {
            approval: [
                {
                    name: 'XXXX',
                    kode: '10'
                },
                {
                    name: 'YYYY',
                    kode: '12'
                },
                {
                    name: 'ZZZZ',
                    kode: '14'
                },
                {
                    name: 'HHHH',
                    kode: '09'
                }
                
            ],
            batas: "10"
        }

    // solution 1 > use for loop:
    const results_1 = [];
    for (let i=0; i<data.approval.length; i++) {
      if (data.approval[i].kode >= data.batas) results_1.push(data.approval[i]);
    }
    console.log(results_1);
    
    // solution 2 > use for...of loop:
    const results_2 = [];
    for (const obj of data.approval) {
      if (obj.kode >= data.batas) results_2.push(obj);
    }
    console.log(results_2);

    // solution 3 > use filter method:
    const results_3 = data.approval.filter(obj => obj.kode >= data.batas);
    console.log(results_3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the es6 javascript code.

First I put the approval array and batas into the variable first.

Then I use for loop iteration to find data less than 10, then I delete it using splice.

The last time I returned it was an object

This is my code :

```js
    const batas = (data) => {
        let arr = data.approval
        let batas = data.batas
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]['kode'] < batas) arr.splice(i, 1)
        }
        return data
    }
    
    let data = {
        approval: [
            {
                name: 'XXXX',
                kode: '10'
            },
            {
                name: 'YYYY',
                kode: '12'
            },
            {
                name: 'ZZZZ',
                kode: '14'
            },
            {
                name: 'HHHH',
                kode: '09'
            }
        ],
        batas: '10'
    }
    
    console.log(batas(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` method can do this, for more info check: [MDN - filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let data = {
        approval: [
            {
                name: 'XXXX',
                kode: '10'
            },
            {
                name: 'YYYY',
                kode: '12'
            },
            {
                name: 'ZZZZ',
                kode: '14'
            },
            {
                name: 'HHHH',
                kode: '09'
            }
            
        ],
        batas: "10"
    }

const filteredData = {approval: data.approval.filter(item => item.kode >= data.batas)}

console.log('filteredData: ', filteredData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#filter` method as follows:

```js
const
    data = { approval: [ { name: 'XXXX', kode: '10' }, { name: 'YYYY', kode: '12' }, { name: 'ZZZZ', kode: '14' }, { name: 'HHHH', kode: '09' } ], batas: "10" },
    
    output = [ data ]
        .map(
            ({approval,batas}) => 
            ({approval:approval.filter(
                ({kode}) => kode >= batas
            )})
        )[0];
        
console.log( output );
```

**However, ....**

If all you need is the *filtered*, array then this approach would suffice:

```js
const
    data = { approval: [ { name: 'XXXX', kode: '10' }, { name: 'YYYY', kode: '12' }, { name: 'ZZZZ', kode: '14' }, { name: 'HHHH', kode: '09' } ], batas: "10" },
    
    output = data.approval
        .filter(
            ({kode}) => kode >= data.batas
        );
        
console.log( output );
```